# Post array limit issue in Apache 2.4.4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to post dynamic array in **Codeigniter**.

For each element in form comes 52 entries.  So if I choose 1 element the post array got 52 elements, 104 for 2 and 156 for 3 and so on...

It works smoothly in Apache 2.2, but in Apache 2.4.4 the controller get limited to get only 166 elements in post array.

The **post_max_size** size in **php.ini** is set to 50M.

But it seems not working....